# Get the value of the function at the top to be used inside the bottom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a simple piece of code, in which I have to use a return value from the function at the top, in the second one. Here's the important part

```
let value = $(document).ready(function dropdownResult() {
  let dataNow = moment(new Date()).format("DDMMYYYY");

  $('#selectDia').on('change', function dropdownResult() {
    let value = $('#selectDia').val();
    if (value == 'hoje') {
      let valueUsar = dataNow;
      console.log(valueUsar)
      return valueUsar
    }

    if (value == 'amanha') {
      let valueUsar = moment(new Date()).add(1, 'day').format("DDMMYYYY");
      console.log(valueUsar);
      return valueUsar
    }

    if (value == 'ontem') {
      let valueUsar = moment(new Date()).add(-1, 'day').format("DDMMYYYY");
      console.log(valueUsar)
      return valueUsar
    }

    console.log(valueUsar)
  })
});

setTimeout(function() {
  let setor = (window.location.href).slice(-4).toUpperCase();
  let setorFilter = $(`#preparando`).children();
  setorFilter.hide();
  let setorSelect = $(`.${setor}`);
  setorSelect.show();
}, 2500);
```

The goal is to hide the DIVs that have the class (".value") on the change of the selection ('#selectDia')

I already tried things like calling `dropdownResult()` inside and store it in a variable inside the second, or calling the variable before the function like `let valueUsar;`, which returns undefined.

What can I do? Thx in advance.

Comment: right off the bat, `let value = $(document).ready(function dropdownResult() {` doesn't make sense. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Event handlers run asynchronously. You can't use the return value in another function.

Comment: You can assign a global variable, and check that in the timeout function.

Comment: Why don't you just hide the matching elements in the `change` handler, instead of in the timeout function? The timeout function only runs once -- what if the user doesn't select anything within 2.5 seconds of the page loading?